# Ruby on Rails Render html syntax gets canceled by "

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to make the word 'Hello' blue with style using html code in Ruby On Rails,  but I get an error of my syntax because the ' " '  cancels my render html. Is there an alternative to use " in render html function? Thanks

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  def hello
    render html: "<h1 style="color:blue;">Hello</h1>"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you have two separated strings `"<h1 style="` and `">Hello</h1>"`.

You could put single quotes around the style instead of double.

```
def hello
    render html: "<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello</h1>".html_safe
end
```

And add [`html_safe`](https://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe) in the end of html string.

> Marks a string as trusted safe.

Comment: Thanks, that was it, now it works